Error: Must supply a TargetProvider to a new TargetableSet. (Magento 2 PWA)
I am getting this error when making a tagList extension for magento 2 PWA from this tutorial.
Create a tag list extension
Error: Must supply a TargetProvider to a new TargetableSet.
at new TargetableSet (/var/www/html/m247p3/pwa-studio-fundamentals/node_modules/tagList/node_modules/@magento/pwa-buildpack/lib/WebpackTools/targetables/TargetableSet.js:28:19)
at TargetableSet.using (/var/www/html/m247p3/pwa-studio-fundamentals/node_modules/tagList/node_modules/@magento/pwa-buildpack/lib/WebpackTools/targetables/TargetableSet.js:23:16)
at module.exports [as intercept] (/var/www/html/m247p3/pwa-studio-fundamentals/node_modules/tagList/src/targets/intercept.js:4:37)
at /var/www/html/m247p3/pwa-studio-fundamentals/node_modules/@magento/pwa-buildpack/lib/BuildBus/BuildBus.js:198:23
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at BuildBus.runPhase (/var/www/html/m247p3/pwa-studio-fundamentals/node_modules/@magento/pwa-buildpack/lib/BuildBus/BuildBus.js:186:20)
at BuildBus.init (/var/www/html/m247p3/pwa-studio-fundamentals/node_modules/@magento/pwa-buildpack/lib/BuildBus/BuildBus.js:167:14)
at configureWebpack (/var/www/html/m247p3/pwa-studio-fundamentals/node_modules/@magento/pwa-buildpack/lib/WebpackTools/configureWebpack/configureWebpack.js:130:9)
at async module.exports (/var/www/html/m247p3/pwa-studio-fundamentals/webpack.config.js:38:20)

What's wrong with TargetableSet? I don't find any solution there.
